# max value of no autonincrement column in update query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to retrieve the maximum value of a key column, increase it and insert it as a new value in the database, like this (pseudo-sql)

```
insert into mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2) 
   values((max(mykeycolumn)+1),'val1','val2');
```

Comment: Why would you do this when you can just set it to be `auto_increment`?

Comment: Because I already have a table in production and cannot change it

Comment: Try `insert into mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2) values((SELECT max(mykeycolumn)+1 FROM mytable),'val1','val2');`

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Sorry mymistake Try `insert into mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2) values((SELECT max(mykeycolumn)+1 FROM mytable) as val,'val1','val2');` add `as val` to the select statement.

Comment: Are you aware that this will not work correctly in an environment where more than one transaction updates the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you `INSERT` from a `SELECT`, but your fixed fields must "come from the `SELECT`" as well, like such:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mykeycolumn, col1, col2) 
   SELECT MAX(mykeycolumn)+1, 'val1', 'val2' 
   FROM mytable;
```

---

**Complementing:** as [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)  pointed out, `MAX() + 1` could cause your problems if you have simultaneous transactions in `mytable`. At some point two identical `mykeycolumn` values would be *generated* and you would get an error. The ideal solution is to convert your table to use *auto_increment*.

Comment: Since the statement is needed only once for a simple import operation, I can ignore this, but thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

You can with this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2) VALUES
     ((SELECT MAX(mykeycolumn) FROM mytable AS foo)+1,'val1','val2');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mykeycolumn, col1, col2) 
     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1, 'val1', 'val2' FROM mytable;
```

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is SQL Server, not MySQL. Even if it were changed to MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID` this answer would be incorrect because the OP isn't working from an auto-increment column.