# max value of no autonincrement column in update query - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In MySQL I can achieve it like this ([max value of no autonincrement column in update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943095/max-value-of-no-autonincrement-column-in-update-query/27943407#27943407)):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2) VALUES
 ((SELECT MAX(mykeycolumn) FROM mytable AS foo)+1,'val1','val2');
```

However, In Oracle, I get an `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

What can I do?

Comment: BTW: this approach is wrong, and may fail in multi-user enironment.

Comment: yes, but I need it for a simple one-user import only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2) VALUES
 ((SELECT MAX(mykeycolumn)+1 FROM mytable),'val1','val2');
```

I.e. move the +1 into the sub-select.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using VALUES?

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mykeycolumn,col1,col2)
 SELECT MAX(mykeycolumn)+1,'val1','val2' FROM mytable
```